# ant build script for behat error

Tags: linux, bash, ant, jenkins, behat

I am trying to setup an ant build script for behat tests so I can run them from jenkins. When I run behat from the command line with bin/behat or ./bin/behat, the output works as expected. But when I use the following ant script

```
<project name="behat" basedir=".">
  <exec dir="bin" executable="./behat">
  </exec>
</project>
```

I get this error:

```
Buildfile: <mydir>/build.xml
 [exec]
 [exec]
 [exec]
 [exec]   [RuntimeException]
 [exec]   Context class not found.
 [exec]   Maybe you have provided wrong or no `bootstrap` path in your behat.yml:
 [exec]   http://docs.behat.org/guides/7.config.html#paths
 [exec]
 [exec]
 [exec]
 [exec] behat [--init] [-f|--format="..."] [--out="..."] [--lang="..."] [--[no-]ansi] [--[no-]time] [--[no-]paths] [--[no-]snippets] [--[no-]snippets-paths] [--[no-]multiline] [--[no-]expand] [--story-syntax] [-d|--definitions="..."] [--name="..."] [--tags="..."] [--cache="..."] [--strict] [--dry-run] [--rerun="..."] [--append-snippets] [--append-to="..."] [features]
 [exec]
 [exec]
 [exec] Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be running behat from the bin directory. It won't find your behat.yml file.

You should either run it like this:

```
./bin/behat
```

or pass a path to the config file:

```
cd bin
./bin/behat --config ../behat.yml
```

I haven't tried the later. Your ant script might look something like:

```
<project name="behat" basedir=".">
  <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="./bin/behat" />
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took ant out of the equation and just used jenkins to run the behat commands directly:

```
cd <mydir>
bin/behat
```

One thing I need to check is the build from jenkins returns failed, but it may be due to the behat tests are failing.